# Error when adding object to Context in seperate Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, model-view-controller

I have a simple app with AppDelegate and MainController - I have passed the managedObjectContext to the MainController (I think successfully) but I receive an error when added an object to the context.

Code:

```
 @implementation AppDelegate

 -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *) aNotification
 {
  // this line is wrong:  MainController *controller = [[MainController alloc] init];
  controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
 }


  @interface MainController : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;


  @implementation MainController

  -(IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {

  NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                               inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext];

   //The above line gives an error
```

ERROR:
+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter search for entity name "Person"

If I change the code and do everything in the AppDelegate, everything works without issues.

I am not sure what is going on.

[EDIT]
I needed to create an IBOutlet from the MainController object in IB to the AppDelegate - thanks Nofel.

Comment: did you @synthesized managedObjectContext in MainController ? and Why don't you make a MainController property in your AppDelegate ?

Comment: Yes, first I had it without the synthesize, then added it - no change.

Comment: ok ... Consider also doing controller.managedObjectContext=[self managedObjectContext]; instead of controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

Comment: No change - same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
Person *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[person setName:someNameTextField]; // if you want to set some properties
[_managedObjectContext save:nil]
```

It depends on how you create your Core-Data model and what you use in you appDelegate.
Best way is to watch some tutorial or Developer Library first.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, just tried it and received the same error. That code works when I have everything in the AppDelegate, but not in the MainController.